# How to use ODB data to detect throttle related emission problem?

Tags: throttle, throttle-position-sensor

Based on OBD II Standard PIDs

PID(hex) 11 Throttle Position value from 0~100%

How could we use this data to predict if there is going to be a problem?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OBD-II_PIDs

Comment: What data do you have? What symptoms do you have? What car do you have? vtc as this is just a link...

Comment: I just wanna to create a general method to detect the relevant problems

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Please take a moment to take [The Tour](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/tour) as well as read through the [Help Pages](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/help).

Answer (score 1):

By using OBD to get some key data, I developed a method to detect "throttle" related emission problems.

=== Background ===

The engine of the vehicle goes into the idle state (engine speed > 0, vehicle speed = 0) when waiting for the traffic lights.
If the engine does not obtain enough air because of a throttle related problem (but not worse enough to flameout), then ECU will control to inject less fuel to maintain an Air/Fuel rate.  The engine speed will drop (a small or big variation).

[image]

=== Method ===

1. monitoring the "engine speed" —— to detect the abnormal variation
2. check the changing rate of the "throttle position" —— to check if the throttle is getting stuck somehow

=== About the Maths ===

S - engine speed

T - target idle RPM

e - variation tolerance of engine speed during the idle state

**if | S - T | > e, then the idling engine speed is not stable**

p - throttle position

t - time

R - the changing rate of the "throttle position"

R = ΔP/Δt

**if | R_max - R_median | > e during a period of time,**

**then we could say that R is not stable, which means, he throttle is getting stuck somehow**

=== Data collected from OBD ===

1. engine speed
2. vehicle speed
3. throttle position

=== welcome to post your thinking ===